# Displaced axis exponents. How to move them back?

Tags: python, matplotlib

[Update with MWE code.]

I successfully make a 3D plot with the simplified code shown below. The only thing that’s not working is that the exponents for each of the axes are moved to below the plot. They’re there, but I can’t get them back to their usual location near the axes. I can only make the exponents visible by rotating the plot (while it’s interactive via `plt.show()`; see image). How do fix this?

I’ve looked at bounding boxes, clipping, formatters, changing the scale of the ‘equalizing’ function; all have no effect on these exponents that are moved almost outside the visible area. When I rotate the interactive plot (generated by `plt.show()`), I can glimpse that they are indeed the exponents, but I also can’t recover/move them in an exported image (with `plt.savefig`).

Package versions used (in case they’re relevant):

```
matplotlib — 3.7.0
python     — 3.10.9
numpy      — 1.24.2
```

The plotting code:

```
# Import statements

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#  Load the data from file

rawdata = np.loadtxt("./JUICEPropagationHistory_Q1.dat", delimiter="\t")

t, x, y, z = rawdata[:, 0],  rawdata[:, 1], rawdata[:, 2], rawdata[:, 3]

# Create the figure, axes, and plot

fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, projection="3d")
# also doesn’t work: ax1 = fig.add_subplot(projection="3d")

traj, = ax1.plot3D(x, y, z,)
# also doesn’t work: traj, = ax1.plot(x, y, z,)

# Show plot

plt.show()
```

Here’s is a subset (10 lines, ie. ten 3D data points (extracted)) of the plot data, and the same problem occurs. NB: the example plot I include below includes the full dataset, of which the first ten lines are given here:

```
1122009840.0    -48024.55642854782  -1074283.2518446227 -2957002.498288834  -493.87486260547803 1592.593075547164   -578.5977602861286
1122009850.0    -52962.51675637561  -1058340.3559710935 -2962741.5162975215 -493.7145926446957  1595.97762488453    -569.2029174306579
1122009860.0    -57898.79608710603  -1042363.868994681  -2968386.4986451087 -493.5386644229466  1599.3112800269291  -559.7906769165551
1122009870.0    -62833.23787599742  -1026354.3003377155 -2973937.2728212336 -493.3470855897769  1602.5939451510817  -550.3613320588779
1122009880.0    -67765.68565708105  -1010312.1603731712 -2979393.669250775  -493.1398642501385  1605.8255259518153  -540.9151765892451
1122009890.0    -72695.9830477127   -994237.9604094768  -2984755.521297978  -492.91700896390864 1609.0059296436052  -531.4525046479761
1122009900.0    -77623.97375311954  -978132.2126753118  -2990022.6652705    -492.67852874540085 1612.1350649620858  -521.9736107762334
1122009910.0    -82549.50157094198  -961995.4303043876  -2995194.940423384  -492.42443306286776 1615.212842165528   -512.4787899081681
1122009920.0    -87472.41039577057  -945828.1273202132  -3000272.188962945  -492.1547318379962  1618.2391730362876  -502.9683373630679
1122009930.0    -92392.54422367772  -929630.8186208482  -3005254.2560505844 -491.869435445394   1621.2139708822224  -493.4425488375083
```

[image: 3D plot with misplaced axis-label exponents]

Comment: Don't do `layout='tight'`

Comment: Unfortunately that seems to have no effect on the problem. Thanks though. I’ve also tried `”constrained"`, `”compressed"` and `None` as `layout` settings.

Comment: Perhaps you could make a self-contained example?  Otherwise its hard to help.